# Python equivalent for MATLAB binofit

Tags: python, python-2.7

In MATLAB, `binofit` returns the maximum likelihood estimate of the success of binomial probability distribution and confidence intervals.

`statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint` returns confidence intervals as well, but couldn't find a function for maximum likelihood estimate of the binomial probability distribution. Is there any function that you can suggest as a `binofit` function in MATLAB for python?

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you suggested is good enough. I ran some test comparing Matlab `binofit` and Python `statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint`. The test was empyrical like testin 100K experiments like `[phat,pci] = binofit(x,n,alpha)` with `min_conf,max_conf = proportion_confint(x,n,alpha=alpha,method='beta')`.

The RMSE bewteen confidence interval limits from Matlab and Python are below 5e-6 for values values of x and n between 0 and 10000. Tested with alpha=0.05 and 0.01.

I know this is not strict demonstrations but for my project I decided to consider the two estimates of confidence intervals as equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of these two libraries: [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/py-modindex.html) or [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/stats.html).

I do not know if it is exactly what you're looking for, but I hope you find it useful still.